# Is the relation $\{(a, b) , (b, a) , (a, a)\}$ transitive?

Tags: relations

I know that for transitive relation if $(A,B)$ and $(B,C)$ exist then $(A,C)$ must also exist but the problem  is that

- If I see $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ exist then $(a,a)$ should exist and yes it does, so transitive.
- If I see $(b,a)$ and $(a,b)$ then $(b,b)$ should exist which does not, so not transitive.

Comment: It's not transitive because of second point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a relation to be transitive, it must be the case that *whenever* you see $(x, y)$ and $(y, z)$, you should also see $(x, z)$.

So even the existence of *one* pair not satisfying that is sufficient to say that it is **not** transitive. (Even if there are tons of other pairs which do satisfy it.)

So, in your case, the relation is not transitive.